# SimJacking protection

Tags: mobile, simcard

How do you protect your mobile phones from [SimJacking](https://thehackernews.com/2019/09/simjacker-mobile-hacking.html)?

Comment: As far as I know the only way you could mitigate against it is ask your mobile operator if your SIM is accepts S@T push commands.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is provided in the link used in the question.

Comment: "How to protect your phone from your ISP?" is too broad and not relevant to SimJacking. The threat of SimJacking has nothing to do with an ISP, and is far wider than your mobile carrier, if that's what you meant instead. As for what to do about this specific threat, the link you used in your question talks about that.

Comment: i was not specifically asking about simjacking, i just thought there are probably more threaths regarding mobile carriors and the techniques they use